# React Native Stack Navigation Screen Doesn't Exist

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

In App.js I have the following Stack Navigator:

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {user ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Home">
            {(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

In the HomeScreen, I am trying to navigate to the "Profile" screen:

```
export default function HomeScreen(props) {
  const onProfilePress = () => {
    props.navigation.navigate('Profile')
  };

  return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onProfilePress}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Profile</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
   );
}
```

However, I get a

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Profile"} was not handled by any navigator.
```

Does anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Profile` is only part of the stack when `user` is true.
Perhaps you meant to do something like this:

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {user ? (
<>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home">
            {(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
<Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
</>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it

Comment: From sign out, I'm trying to redirect back to Login. But I am facing the same issue. Is this flow possible? If not, can I somehow disable the ability to go back in the Login screen?